# TeamCity cannot run process dotnet cli

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, teamcity, dotnet-cli

Установил TeamCity, пытаюсь построить проект на .net core.
TeamCity запускается как служба от моего пользователя (администратор)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал от системного пользователя. Но в таком случае на этапе скачивания исходников из репозитория, build agent зависает и отмена задачи даже не срабатывает. При запуске службы от моего пользователя, скачивание проходит корректно

Для построения проекта на .net core использую плагин teamcity-dotnet-plugin

На этапе dotnet restore выдается ошибка:

> Cannot run process: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\dotnet" (in directory "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5e6119f461b35e68"): CreateProcess error=5, Отказано в доступе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права доступа у моего пользователя в файлу dotnet.exe есть. Подскажите как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась добавлением переменной среды (environment variable)

```
DOTNET_HOME=C:\Program Files\dotnet\
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: интересно почему запускать от имени этого пользователя, а не от системного?  попробуй запустить от системного и убрать параметр из среды окружения. 
тут есть проблема одна: для каждого билд-агента ты должен будешь   именно в папку C:\Program Files\dotnet\ класть все и указывать параметры